# cual es el error de este codigo php?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

```
<?php

//paso 1 es conectarnos con el servidor //esta manera ya esta obsoleta!!
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if(!$link){
        echo'No Se Pudo Establecer Conexion Con El Servidor: '. mysql_error();
    }else{
    //Paso 2 es seleccionar la base de datos
        $base = mysql_select_db('full',$link);
        if(!$base){
            echo'No se encontro la base de datos: '.mysql_error();
        }else{
    //Paso 3 es hacer la sentencia sql y ejecutarla
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM full";
            $ejecuta_sentencia = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$ejecuta_sentencia){
                echo'hay un error en la sentencia de sql: '.$sql;
            }else{
    //Paso 4 es traer los resultados como un array para imprirlos en pantalla
                $full = mysql_fetch_array($ejecuta_sentencia);}



        }
    }

function portada($full){

 $salida = $salida . '<div class="col-md-4">';
 $salida = $salida . '<h2>' . $full["nombre"] . '</h2>';
 $salida = $salida . '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. base64_encode($full['imagen']) .'" alt="'. $full['nombre'] . '" class="">';
 $salida = $salida . '<p>' . $full['descripcion'] . '</p>';
 $salida = $salida . '<p><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#"> Antes ' . $full['precio'] . '<strong> Ahora ' . $full['precio']. '</strong></a></p> </div>';        




return $salida;
}




?>
```

Comment: y ¿cuál es el error que te esta retornando, ya usaste el código, que mas nos puedes comentar al respecto? saludos y bienvenido

Comment: Dos errores que veo es que estas utilizando `mysql_query` en vez de `mysqli_query` y a parte de pasarle `$sql` tambien le tienes que pasar `$link`

Comment: deberían prohibir las preguntas que titulen **cual es el error de este codigo?**

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración **deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta**. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Estás utilizando las `mysql_*`, las cuales a la hora de programar en php no son seguras. Deberías usar las `mysqli_*`.

Y lo segundo, tal y como dice Mario, tu sentencia `$sql` requiere tambien de `$link` para ejecutarse. Sin ella produce un error.

Aun así sería conveniente que nos dieras mas detalles sobre tu error en concreto.

Answer (score 0):

Además de las respuestas que te han escrito, debo preguntar: 
**¿la base de datos y tabla se llaman igual: "full"?**

Estás seleccionando la base de datos "full" usando:

```
mysql_select_db('full',$link);
```

Y haciendo un query sobre una tabla llamada "full":

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM full";
```

En lugar de usar mysql_* o mysqli_* considero que deberías usar **PDO** que actualmente tiene soporte y no mysql__ o mysqli__